# Paperclip error on submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I am using `paperclip` gem to manipulate image and have it in my `Gemfile`. I have also installed `ImageMagick` and is I give command `which convert` or `which identify`, I get `/opt/ImageMagick/bin/` back.

So in my `development.rb` I have added

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/opt/ImageMagick/bin/"
```

My controller code to handle creation of post -

```
def create  
  @post = Post.create(post_params)
  redirect_to posts_path
end

private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:image, :caption)
  end
```

Model for `Post`

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :image, presence: true

  has_attached_file :image, styles: { :medium => "640x" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

Although when I hit submit from view page, I am getting error as -

```
Paperclip::Error in PostsController#create
There was an error processing the thumbnail for
```

Terminal output -

```
Processing by PostsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",    "authenticity_token"=>"eBXNVsIDE9vuiHgesSPm+mcWiNMz9s0Vgot27HKZl8uK+UUF5P6YnL47SW65Z0taX1GtGPYzceN+HvDseVA/Ow==", "post"=>{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f810f984508 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/nq/mk1lf5tj5_z4n9tyg0wtkmy80000gq/T/RackMultipart20150823-28735-1t6e63j.jpg>, @original_filename="IndiaEpic.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"post[image]\"; filename=\"IndiaEpic.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "caption"=>"india"}, "commit"=>"Create Post"}
Command :: PATH=/opt/ImageMagick/bin/:$PATH; file -b --mime '/var/folders/nq/mk1lf5tj5_z4n9tyg0wtkmy80000gq/T/2e0348f0f5226c94029d825fc44da2cd20150823-28735-1vy891l.jpg'
Command :: PATH=/opt/ImageMagick/bin/:$PATH; identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/nq/mk1lf5tj5_z4n9tyg0wtkmy80000gq/T/2e0348f0f5226c94029d825fc44da2cd20150823-28735-1exazk5.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: PATH=/opt/ImageMagick/bin/:$PATH; identify -format %m '/var/folders/nq/mk1lf5tj5_z4n9tyg0wtkmy80000gq/T/2e0348f0f5226c94029d825fc44da2cd20150823-28735-1exazk5.jpg[0]'
Command :: PATH=/opt/ImageMagick/bin/:$PATH; convert '/var/folders/nq/mk1lf5tj5_z4n9tyg0wtkmy80000gq/T/2e0348f0f5226c94029d825fc44da2cd20150823-28735-1exazk5.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "640x640" '/var/folders/nq/mk1lf5tj5_z4n9tyg0wtkmy80000gq/T/18ed538b6a2c563c650b284627c4609d20150823-28735-modfab'
```

Would appreciate any help to resolve this error. Let me know if I need to add in more details.

Comment: Can you post your model code file to help further resolve this question?

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake in the `Post` model. The `has_attached_file` is correct but the `styles:` is throwing a exception because you didn't specify the correct dimensions for the image

You have the following:

```
has_attached_file :image, styles: { :medium => "640x" } # forgot to add your width in the string.
```

Try changing to this:

```
has_attached_file :image, styles: { :medium => "640x640" }
```

Comment: You could export ImageMagick into $PATH and modify your development.rb and comment out Paperclip options. `source /opt/ImageMagick/bin/`  and restart your terminals and rails server when doing this.

Comment: My `echo $PATH` output - `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin:/Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/ImageMagick/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/bin`

Comment: What happens if you echo ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_history or ~/.bash_profile?

Comment: `/Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.bashrc` and for `.bash_history`, `.bash_profile` accordingly.

Comment: Peek at `.bashrc` by going into vim editor and make sure that you have ImageMagick in there. Protip: sudo vim ~/.bashrc

Comment: `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
 ### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
 export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"`
This is in my `.bashrc`, so should I go ahead and add ImageMagick after line 3?

Comment: [Let's move this discussion into chat for further troubleshooting.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88110/room-for-rodrigo-argumedo-and-aniruddha)